# Select newest record where multiple records exist from where/like statement

Tags: sql

Forgive me if the title (and my SQL knowledge) seems a bit vague but I will try and explain as clearly as I can.

I have a table `DVE_GroupMember`, in which `Person_StaffNumber` is a unique identifier for a person. In this table is a column `GroupMember_GroupName` which contains a group name that a person can be assigned to.

There is also column `GroupMember_StartDate` which signified when that person was assigned to that `GroupMember_GroupName`.

A person can have been assigned to various groups over a period of time, so if I run the following SQL, I get multiple results for the various `Person_StaffNumber` values in the database (where the group name contains 'muster')

```
select * 
from DVE_GroupMember 
where GroupMember_GroupName like 'muster%'
```

What I am trying to do, is select the most recent `GroupMember_GroupName` that each person has been assigned to.

I have tried the following syntax but it is generating the error 'incorrect syntax near ')'

```
select * 
from DVE_GroupMember 
where GroupMember_GroupName like 'muster%' 
    and GroupMember_StartDate = (SELECT MAX(GroupMember_StartDate)
```

Would anyone be able to help me with this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
    * 
FROM
    DVE_GroupMember GM
WHERE
    GroupMember_GroupName LIKE 'muster%'
    AND GroupMember_StartDate = (
        SELECT
            MAX(GroupMember_StartDate)
        FROM
            DVE_GroupMember _GM
        WHERE
            _GM.GroupMember_GroupName LIKE 'muster%'
            AND _GM.Person_StaffNumber = GM.Person_StaffNumber)
```

Comment: This lists the latest group entry beginning with "muster".  But the OP is looking for the latest group per staff member.

Comment: I beg to differ but am not impossible to persuade otherwise. As he's only interested in 'muster%' that's the only thing you need to consider for the max date.

Comment: I think the key statement in the OP's question is _"What I am trying to do, is select the most recent GroupMember_GroupName that **each** person has been assigned to."_ This would only return the latest person to be added to a group like 'Muster%'. If this is what the OP was after then using `SELECT TOP 1 ... WHERE GroupMember_GroupName LIKE 'Muster%' ORDER BY GroupMember_StartDate DESC` Would be a more efficient solution anyway.

Comment: Each person group name = 'muster%'... not all.

Comment: @Asken: your edit fixes the problem I mentioned, but introduces a new one.  As written now, both sides of `_GM.Person_StaffNumber = Person_StaffNumber` refer to the same table.  You should alias the outer query instead.

Comment: it just took a bit of thinking... :) fixed the alias too. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try the following:

```
select * 
from DVE_GroupMember 
where GroupMember_GroupName like 'muster%' 
    and GroupMember_StartDate = (SELECT MAX(GroupMember_StartDate) from DVE_GroupMember where GroupMember_GroupName like 'muster%')
```

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server you coud use `cross apply`, like:

```
select   Staff.Person_StaffNumber
,        LastGroup.GroupMember_GroupName
from     (
         select  distinct Person_StaffNumber
         from    DVE_GroupMember 
         ) as Staff
cross apply
         (
         select  top 1 gm.GroupMember_GroupName
         from    DVE_GroupMember gm
         where   Staff.Person_StaffNumber = gm.Person_StaffNumber
         order by
                 GroupMember_StartDate desc
         ) as LastGroup
```

Answer (score 0):

This will give you people where the latest group is like Muster

```
SELECT  gm.*
FROM    DVE_GroupMember gm
        INNER JOIN
        (   SELECT  Person_StaffNumber, MAX(GroupMember_StartDate) [MaxStartDate]
            FROM    DVE_GroupMember
            GROUP BY Person_StaffNumber
        ) MaxGm
            ON gm.Person_StaffNumber = MaxGm.Person_StaffNumber
            AND gm.MaxStartDate = maxGm.GroupMember_StartDate
WHERE   GroupMember_GroupName LIKE 'muster%'
```

and this will give you the latest group per staff member where the group is like Muster

```
SELECT  gm.*
FROM    DVE_GroupMember gm
        INNER JOIN
        (   SELECT  Person_StaffNumber, MAX(GroupMember_StartDate) [MaxStartDate]
            FROM    DVE_GroupMember
            WHERE   GroupMember_GroupName LIKE 'muster%'
            GROUP BY Person_StaffNumber
        ) MaxGm
            ON gm.Person_StaffNumber = MaxGm.Person_StaffNumber
            AND gm.MaxStartDate = maxGm.GroupMember_StartDate
```

I could not work out exactly which you required.